# PowerShell replace the first three spaces with commas

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a file that looks like this. There are many lines in this format.

```
5/10 RED SYSID This is a long message
```

I would like to have these line be in 4 comma-separated columns.

```
5/10,RED,SYSID,This is a long message
```

How can I replace only the first three spaces with commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should do what you want.

```
$line -replace '^(\S+?) (\S+?) (\S+?) (.*)','$1,$2,$3,$4'
```

This captures four groups of non-whitespace characters separated by spaces, with the last group containing the remainder of the string.  Then it replaces them with those same four groups separated by commas.

To use this to modify every matching line in a file, Pipe `Get-Content` through `Foreach-Object` and finally to `Out-File`

```
$regex = [regex]'^(\S+?) (\S+?) (\S+?) (.*)','$1,$2,$3,$4'

Get-Content $filename | foreach {
  $_ -replace $regex
} | Out-File $newfilename
```

Any lines the regex does not match will be sent to the output file unchanged.  This includes if any lines contain tabs instead of spaces.  If you need to test for this in your script, you can first test for `$_ -match $regex`, and take appropriate action if that returns false.

Comment: Forgive me, I am not sure how to use this in my script. Would $line be my log file, or would I need to get-content and feed the file into this statement?

Comment: Perfect, works great.    gc $colums | foreach { $_ -replace '^(\S+?) (\S+?) (\S+?) (.*)','$1,$2,$3,$4' } | out-file $removespace

Comment: The script breaks if it hits multiple white spaces in a row. I have done some testing and I am not sure why. I have tried taking the ? out of (S+?) I did test with -match $regex and it returns false.

Comment: To handle multiple whitespaces, put a + on the space between matches, like so: `'^(\S+?) +(\S+?) +(\S+?) +(.*)'`  This treats multiple spaces in a row as one space.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the PowerShell `-split` and `-join` operators.

```
$line -split ' ',3 -join ','
```

This example will convert the first three spaces into commas.  `-split ' ',3` will split the string into an array of four elements separated by the first three spaces in the string.  Then `-join ','` will rejoin them into one string with a comma between each.

The above won't work if your input has multiple spaces between fields since each space is considered separately, or if your fields are separated by other whitespace such as tabs.  Instead, use a regex split.

```
$line -split '\s+',3,"RegexMatch" -join ','
```

This example treats as a delimiter the first three matches of `\s+` and converts a sequence of consecutive whitespace into a single comma.

To run against every line in a file, use `Get-Content` and `Foreach-Object`

```
Get-Content $filename | foreach {
  $_ -split '\s+',3,"RegexMatch" -join ','
} | Out-File $newfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for.

[Replace the first occurence of a string in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449343/replace-the-first-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-file)

The relevant code is this:

```
$re = [regex]' '
$re.Replace([string]::Join("`n", (gc C:\Path\To\test.txt)), ',', 3)
```