# Powershell how to replace only given number of matches?

Tags: xml, powershell, batch-file, windows-10

I'm trying to write a batch script on Windows 10.

In an XML file, I have multiple "version" tags. With powershell I want to replace only first 2 of them.

```
powershell -Command "(gc example.xml) -replace '(?s)<version>.*?</version>', '<version>2.0.0</version>' | Out-File example.xml"
```

But this code replaces all of them. How can I replace just only 2 of them?

Comment: `for-loops` is the magical word you are looking for.

Comment: Can you give me a santizied version of your `example.xml` file.  When I say sanitized, I mean replace any IP address, computer names, domain names, account names, etc.

Comment: I would like to but I'm not allowed :(

Comment: The usual answer is, "Don't use regular expressions to update XML files."

Comment: loops + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449343/replace-the-first-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-file

Comment: Powershell has native capability to read and write XML files.

Comment: It's worth pointing out again (as @Squashman said) that PowerShell has native support for XML using `XmlDocument`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449755/3608792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally agree that xml files should be edited with xml tools,
and I thought it wasn't possible to cram it into a one liner - but the [interesting link gvee provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449660/6811411) transforms this `example.xml`

```
> type .\example.xml
<version>1.0.1</version>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<version>1.0.3</version>
<version>1.0.4</version>
```

---

```
powershell -Nop -C "$RE=[RegEx]'(?<=<version>).*(?=</version>)';$RE.Replace([string]::Join(\"`n\",(gc '.\example.xml')),'2.0.0',2)"
```

---

```
<version>2.0.0</version>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<version>1.0.3</version>
<version>1.0.4</version>
```

Append the `|Set-Content` or `|Out-File` yourself.

**Edit: a slightly simpler version requiring PSv3+ for the `Get-Content -raw` parameter**

```
powershell -Nop -C "$RE=[RegEx]'(?<=<version>).*(?=</version>)';$RE.Replace((gc '.\example.xml' -raw),'2.0.0',2)"
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you.